# Resampling when using image as Texture

Tags: image-processing, image, textures

How to get sharp pixel boundaries with Texture? I'd like to have only black/white in the example below, no gray.

```
a := Image[Table[If[EvenQ[x + y], 1, 0], {x, 50}, {y, 50}]];
Graphics[{Texture[a],
  Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {0.5, 1}, {0, 0}}]}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not too hard.

```
a = Image[Table[If[EvenQ[x + y], 1, 0], {x, 50}, {y, 50}], ImageSize -> Large];

Graphics[{Texture[a], Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}},
                              VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {0.5, 1}, {0, 0}}]}]
```

[image: textured triangle]

Comment: That's much better, thank you. On a PDF export, still have gray transitions, however. Do you know if this is avoidable?

Comment: Ah, that I don't know about. Could you mention what version and OS are you on, to help with the diagnosis?

Comment: Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on Windows 8, 64-bit

Comment: Hmm... do you also get the gray transitions if you export `a` as a PDF?

Comment: Yes, they are still there (you have to zoom-in to see them). I think that the image in your answer also has gray transitions if you zoom in. My understanding is that the `Texture` method uses some sort of interpolation on the image and if it happens to land between pixels, you get a  mixture of adjacent pixels, just as `ImageValue[a, {1, 1}]` gives gray.

Comment: "I think that the image in your answer also has gray transitions if you zoom in" - well, since you did say that `a` itself displays those transitions, that's no surprise. You are right, `Texture[]` internally does linear interpolation of gray levels (RGB components in general). I don't have other ideas on how to checkerboard a polygon, tho.

Comment: Displaying/exporting `a` gives sharp pixels. Only if you manually extract colors between pixels with `ImageValue` you get gray. Anyway, I can live with your solution, thanks again.

Comment: @Frank, If you `Binarize` your output does that give you what you are looking for?

Comment: @bobthechemist: For B/W, yes, although I have not measured if now either black or white pixels appear larger. On color images, it does not work. I think, it's a fundamental issue with the way `Texture` is implemented. I'd love it if there was an option like `Resampling -> "Nearest"` in `ImageResize` for `Texture`.

Comment: @Frank, it is indeed a bit unfortunate that one cannot tweak the interpolation used internally by `Texture[]`. Maybe in a future version...