# Sharp background image in plot

Tags: plotting, image, textures

How do I get rid of blurry transitions between pixels of the background image below. It's the fault of `Texture[]`, previously discussed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25454/6208).

I haven't been able to get good results with `ImageCompose[]` or the other answers in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23003/6208). I'd like to avoid manual white margins that have to be adjusted if the image size changes or the font size of tick marks changes.

The best solution I've found so far is to manually scale `a` up using `ImageResize[]` before using it as Texture. It reduces blurry transitions, but does not get rid of them.

```
a = Import["http://i.imgur.com/PiLKV6S.png"];
Show[ParametricPlot[{20 + 1.4 x - 40 y, x}, {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 1},
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Purple, Thick], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 201}, {0, 144}},
  Prolog -> {Texture[a],
    Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1}]},
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
    }]]
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `Resampling -> "Nearest"` in the `ImageResize`.

Comment: I tried that. It reduces blurry transitions, but does not get rid of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you can control the interpolation used by `Texture`. One option might be to embed the image as a `Raster` primitive instead.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{20 + 1.4 x - 40 y, x}, {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Purple, Thick], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 201}, {0, 144}}, 
  Prolog -> {Raster @ Reverse @ ImageData @ a}]]
```

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using a combination of nearest resampling and a large size (e.g. 2000 pixels) should do the trick.

```
a = ImageResize[Import["http://i.imgur.com/PiLKV6S.png"], {2000}, 
Resampling -> "Nearest"];
Show[ParametricPlot[{20 + 1.4 x - 40 y, x}, {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Purple, Thick], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 201}, {0, 144}}, 
 Prolog -> {Texture[a], 
 Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], 
  Scaled[{0, 1}]}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It reduces blurry transitions, but does not get rid of them. There are now over 30 different colors in this tiny part of the image: http://i.imgur.com/NLfmoyi.png

Comment: The image, when uploaded to stack exchange, does show some blurring.  However, from what I can see, the image output in Mathematica shows no such blurry transitions.  Try for yourself and let us know.

Comment: When I export the image created with ImageResize 2000, and then zoom in using Acrobat or MS Paint, I see exactly the image I uploaded.